# Implement Gocardless webhook in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, webhooks, gocardless

I was trying to implement a webhook in laravel.

I have created access token and created webhook endpoint also.

my webhook end point is like,https://www.example.com/gocardless.php

and my route is like,

```
Route::get('/gocardless.php', 
'\App\Http\Controllers\gocardlessController@remote')->name('remote');
```

Controller code like,

```
class gocardlessController extends Controller
 {


  public function remote(Request $request)
  {

 $token ="token";

 $raw_payload = file_get_contents('php://input');

 $headers = getallheaders();


 $provided_signature = $headers["Webhook-Signature"];
 $calculated_signature = hash_hmac("sha256",$raw_payload,$token);
 if ($provided_signature == $calculated_signature) {

  $payload = json_decode($raw_payload, true);
   }
   }
   }
```

But when i clik on send test webhook in gocardless account,they are given "405 no method found" as responce.

How i can solve this?

Comment: Your route must be in routes/web.php and you do not need to write \App\Http\Controllers in route.

Comment: @Reshma Did completed implementation gocardless in your laravel project?

Comment: @AlauddinAhmed Yes.

Comment: @Reshma can you help me out? I'm having an error in webhook in test environment. Giving me 419 authentication timeout error. I'm using laravel 5.5

Comment: @AlauddinAhmed Sure.Can you show your code and tell me where is the exact issue is coming

Comment: @Reshma checkout here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53805342/gocardless-webhook-419-authentication-timeout-error

Comment: @Reshma i am new with gocardless i have some integration with laravel and I'm having an error in webhook in test environment. Giving me 419 authentication timeout error. please help me.

Answer (score 3):

The [HTTP 405 error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) you're seeing indicates that your Laravel application doesn't know how to handle the [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) of the incoming request.

[GoCardless webhooks use the POST method](https://developer.gocardless.com/getting-started/api/staying-up-to-date-with-webhooks/#building-a-webhook-handler) to send you a request with a JSON body, but the route you've written is for handling a GET request (`Route::get`). To resolve this, you should [define a route](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#basic-routing) for POST requests to the endpoint which will receive webhooks.

Comment: I have changed it with (Route::post).But now it throws other error like "500 internal server error"

Comment: @Reshma your code is likely raising an exception which you are not handling. You should catch that exception and inspect it to see what the actual error is (at a guess, it's probably not related to Laravel or GoCardless!) http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php is the PHP documentation for exception handling, which should be a good starting point for this topic.

Answer (score 2):

A few remarks and fixes

## Remark

Why do you include the "ugly" .php extension in your route, there is no need for that

## Fix

Change your route (in web.php) to

```
Route::get('gocardless', 'gocardlessController@remote');
```

## Remark

I also see you start your controller name with lowercase, this is not common practise

## Fix

Don't forget to add these lines in your controller at the top

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers; // declare right namespace

use Illuminate\Http\Request; // Hint which Request class to use below
```

For the body: that you really have to write yourself and return the data as json for example