# gocardless webhook 419 Authentication Timeout error

Tags: laravel-5, gocardless

I'm trying to integrate gocardless webhook in my website. I'm developing my site in laravel 5.5. Right now i'm following their instrution. But getting an error 419 Authentication Timeout. I did exactly as followed from their documentation. https://developer.gocardless.com/getting-started/api/staying-up-to-date-with-webhooks/

I created a POST route in my web.php file
Route::post('/test', 'GocardlessWebhookController@remote');

Then i put my secret token in my env file. In the controller i copy paste the same code from that site. Then i trigger the webhook from sandbox test environment.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: have you change he CSRF token for the webhook page?

Comment: can you give me an example or show what u used in your controller if it is not same.! i'm not using any csrf token.

Comment: please refer this link.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47713243/implement-gocardless-webhook-in-laravel?noredirect=1#comment94520713_47713243

Comment: and just mention your page name in csrftoken.php in middleware folder as except url

Comment: I'm using Route::post.. But i will checkout the csrf as you said.. Thank you..

Comment: if the explanation helps you.please upvote for my answer in my post.Thanks

Comment: I already upvote your question, And you should make an answer so i can mark it as a right answer. 

one more thing, I'm almost close to it. My response is showing 200 but response body is not showing anything. using the same code as in doc . https://developer.gocardless.com/getting-started/api/staying-up-to-date-with-webhooks/